# Simple JavaScript Query

Tags: javascript, function, class

I'm just beginning to learn Javascript and I'm currently trying to use it to change the HTML of an anchor tag. I'd rather not do this by each ID as I will eventually have a few of the same anchors so I wanted to do it with a class.

```
    <div class="testing2">
            <a  href="http://802.f5f.myftpupload.com/11550-2/design/11544/" class="wpc-customize-product">Customize</a>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 

           var test = document.getElementsByClassName('testing2');
           var anchors = test.getElementsByTagName('a');
            if (anchors[0]) {
                anchors[0].innerHTML="Blank";
}


        </script>
```

Problem is, I can make this work when using an id but not when using the class - I receive the error Uncaught TypeError: test.getElementsByTagName is not a function.

What am I missing?

Comment: You will have to use `for` loop or `test`[0]. getElementByClass returns an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `querySelector` to achieve this as

```
document.querySelectorAll('.testing2 a')[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `test` contains an array but you're not calling it as one.

```
var anchors = test[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Answer (score 0):

1st you need `querySelectorAll('.testing2 a')` to select all `a` element inside the element with class `.testing2`

2nd you need a forEach loop to loop through all the element selected and process to update innerHTML to Blank.

```html
<div class="testing2">
  <a href="http://802.f5f.myftpupload.com/11550-2/design/11544/" class="wpc-customize-product"> Customize1</a>
  <a href="http://802.f5f.myftpupload.com/11550-2/design/11544/" class="wpc-customize-product"> Customize2</a>
  <a href="http://802.f5f.myftpupload.com/11550-2/design/11544/" class="wpc-customize-product"> Customize3</a>
  <a href="http://802.f5f.myftpupload.com/11550-2/design/11544/" class="wpc-customize-product"> Customize4</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var testing2 = document.querySelectorAll('.testing2 a');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(testing2, function(el) {
    el.innerHTML = "Blank";
  });
</script>
```